# What is the algorithm used in the function Magnitude.most_similar() in the pymagnitude library?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out the algorithm of the most_similar function in the pymagnitude library.

I have tried to go to their documentation but the algorithm that they used is not included there

```
   vector = (magnitude_file)
   vector.most_similar("king", topn=10)
```

I'm guessing they used interpolation search but I don't know if i'm right.

P.S Can Someone Help?

Comment: Does this (https://gitlab.com/Plasticity/magnitude/blob/master/pymagnitude/__init__.py#L1521-1537) help? This is what it does (https://gitlab.com/Plasticity/magnitude/blob/master/pymagnitude/__init__.py#L1366-1492) there are a few comments in the `_db_query_similarity` logic.

Comment: This is helpful. So this means I'm wrong thinking that they are using interpolation search instead they used cosine similarity, correct me if i'm wrong.